# websocket - Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: ssl, go, websocket

Can't connect to websocket server..

I use the exact same `private.key` and `public.crt` that I use with `nginx`

The cert is self-signed but works fine with the rest of the website over HTTPS via nginx

The websocket server works when using `ws://` when the line with `http.ListenAndServe()` is uncommented

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const PORT uint = 8000

func main(){
    host := parse_flags()

    hub := newHub()
    go hub.run()

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        serve(hub, w, r)
    })

    server_host := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, PORT)

    log.Println("Server listening on:", server_host)

    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(server_host, fmt.Sprintf("/var/ini/ssl/%s/public.crt", host), fmt.Sprintf("/var/ini/ssl/%s/private.key", host), nil)
    //err := http.ListenAndServe(server_host, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your client side?

Comment: `new WebSocket('wss://domain:8000/');`

Comment: I have a very similar error getting this message. I have three browsers on my computer and only Chrome (57) will throw this error. No clue why.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error, but I don't know your urls.

I used `https://localhost:port` for HTTPS and `wss://127.0.0.1:port` for WS.
So I had to accept the cert for `https://localhost` and `https://127.0.0.1` (only in Chrome).

Comment: I browsed to BOTH urls and accepted the certs in the browser :)

Comment: Thanks, for myself I had to navigate to `https://localhost:8080/` accept the development certs

Answer (score 7):

It looks like newest version of Chrome now rejects SHA-1 certs as being insecure. You probably need to move to SHA-2 certs.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue and many others until I realized I was looking in the wrong place for my key files all together!

First off, the cert and key both need to be .PEM files. I'm using Let's Encrypt, so it was a little easier for me to find the right place (which was */etc/letsencrypt/live/domainName*).

If you used a wizard to install your SSL certificate like I did, then you'll need to do a little research on the certificate provider. Just look up where your keys are installed by them and find the .PEM files that seem appropriate for a "cert" and "key".