# Websocket is not working with SSL

Tags: websocket, openssl, mqtt, wss

https://www.hi-todd.com/websocket/

I have created one demo with MQTT protocol and it is working fine with HTTP connection. But when I tried to change HTTP to https then it is getting a connection error.

I have added certificate path in mosquitto.conf file. Let me share with you Mosquitto config path.

```
# WebSockets over TLS/SSL
listener 8083
protocol websockets
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/hi-todd_com.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/hi-todd_com.p7b
```

I have used below library code.

```
https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-websocket.html
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you generate your own certificates or are using an public CA for the broker? Also have you opened port 8083 in what ever firewall is on the hosting service as I can't connect to the port for the ip address in `config.js`

Comment: @hardillb I am using Public CA. 
Yes my port is open. I have tested with http with same port and it was working fine. 

Currently I have changed port and change library for mosquitto websocket emqtt.
https://github.com/emqtt/emqttd/wiki/WebSocket

But getting same issue in this library also. Work in http with ws only.

Comment: Your config.js is pointing to 8084 the config says 8083

Comment: @hardillb For http I used 8083 and for Https, I used 8084. I used this library https://github.com/emqtt/emqttd/wiki/WebSocket. Http is working fine but not https.

Comment: That's emqttd not mosquitto which is what the question talks about

Comment: @hardillb - I have used emqttd but getting same error. But now I have configured again mosquitto in this url.

Comment: Config file:

host = '192.64.114.240';
port = 8083;
topic = 'xyz/1.132443464';
useTLS = true;
username = '';
password = '';

 path = "/mqtt";
cleansession = true;

Comment: Your keyfile needs to be pem encoded not p7b

Comment: my mosquitto config file:

port 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 8083
protocol websockets
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/hi-todd_com.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/hi-todd_com.p7b

Comment: @hardillb I have created private key but still getting error like:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.64.114.240:8083/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: @hardillb Now I verifed my key in thirdparty software and it is correct. (Private key matches the certificate.)  https://decoder.link/matcher

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699051/websocket-error-in-connection-establishment-neterr-insecure-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now we've fixed all the other issues.

The certificate you are using has a CN of `hi-todd.com` and has alternate CNs of

```
DNS:hi-todd.com, DNS:www.hi-todd.com
```

This means it's only valid for those hosts. In your config.js you are referencing the host by it's IP address so it will not match the certificate. This will cause the browser to reject the connection as insecure.

To fix this make your `config.js` use the hostname not the ip address.