# How to connect MQTT on HTTPS server?

Tags: https, mqtt, mosquitto

We are facing the issue in MQTT connection in HTTPS server. Sometimes it is working fine and sometimes it is getting an error like below.

WebSocket connection to 'wss://MYHOST:8083/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

**Let me share with you,**

**My mosquitto.conf file:**

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
listener 1883


listener 8083 
protocol websockets
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/myhost.crt
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/myhost.key
```

**My Mosquitto WebSocket config file:**

```
host = 'MYHOST'; // hostname or IP address 
port = 8083;
topic = 'TOPIC'; // topic to subscribe to
useTLS = true;
username = "";
password = "";
path = "/mqtt";
cleansession = true;
```

Please give me solution for this.

Thanks!

Regards,
Karmdip Joshi

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also are you using a self generated certificate or one issued by a public CA? If self signed is the CA imported into the browser? Also if self signed what signing algorithm did you use?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Browser.
and sorry hardillb But whats the meaning of CA?

Comment: @hardillb please you can explain me What is the meaning of CA?

Comment: CA stands for Certificate Authority

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websocket is not working with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560795/websocket-is-not-working-with-ssl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting same error before few days and got solution from hardillb.

Pls follow below stackoverflow url and try it!!

[Websocket is not working with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560795/websocket-is-not-working-with-ssl)

Thanks.